# Embed web component (text) in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

All,

I want to insert some text and number from a given URL into an Excel spreadsheet.  Is there a good way to do that?

More specifically, I want to incorporate some of the info in the table "Nutrition Information" from this page:

http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/beef-products/3271/2

Many thanks,

JDelage

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: can you give a little more information about what you are trying to do, perhaps an example of the result you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Excel 2007

From menu Data/Get External Data/From Web

opens a form:

- paste address;(eg `http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/beef-products/3271/2)`) and click Go
- web page is displayed (I get a script error, just click Yes, it doesn't seem to matter)
- scroll down to the table you want
- select it with the little yellow arrow thingy
- Click Import

Voila, data is in excel!